# get the name of the child table when joining multiple tables to a parent table

Tags: postgresql, join

I have 4 postgres tables:

- Fruit with attribute freshness (int) that goes to 1 to 5 and a serial id pk
- Banana with curvature  (int) that goes from 0 to 360 and a serial id pk that is both foreign key to fruit and bananas primary key
- Apple with color as text and the same fk pk id
- pineapple with weight as int and the same fk id as the other two

Heres an example for a fruit (you can imagine the others, they are very similar):

```
CREATE TABLE apple
(
    color text,
    id int primary key references fruit(id)
)
```

Heres how I can get all apples and bananas in a single query:

```
select * from fruit
natural full join apple
natural full join banana
WHERE (apple.id is NOT NULL OR banana.id IS NOT NULL);
```

Now I would also like to add a type field to this query, so I know which ones are bananas and which are bananas and which are apples. I know I could just check in code if color is undefined in this particular instance, but there may be another fruit later that also has a color. I could also you use a type field in the fruit table, but that would be redundant information and theres also no real way to enforce relational consistency, which means its easier for mistakes to happen.
So is there a way to add the child table name to the resulting query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can qualify each table column and check them for non-nullity in a case statement

```sql
select *,
  case 
    when apple.id is not null then 'apple' 
    when banana.id is not null then 'banana' 
    else 'i_forgot_to_update_my_query_when_adding_a_new_fruit' 
  end as fruitType
from fruit
 natural full join apple
 natural full join banana
WHERE (apple.id is NOT NULL OR banana.id IS NOT NULL);
```